# SQLCMD in bat file can no longer query Database on Network Server

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

Hi I'm looking for some advice on what changes to look for on our server.

I have successfully been using a bat file on users desktops to query a stock database held on one of our network servers.
I have a few other bat files used for similar tasks and they have all of a sudden stopped working.

We have MS SQL Server 2012 on the database server, and using XP & Win 7 desktops. The DB is on SERVER2 and instance name MSSQL2012
The .bat file is like below

```
    set /P sn= Enter Serial: %=%
sqlcmd -S SERVER2\MSSQL2012 -i C:\SerialCheck\SerialNumber.sql -o C:\SerialCheck\Output.txt -v serial=%sn%
```

and the SerialNumber.sql is like below

```
 USE DATABASE

 GO

select tblStock.SerialNumber,tblStock.StockD,tblStock.YearManufacture,tblStock.Price 
FROM tblStock
where SerialNumber like '%$(sn)%' 

GO
```

It was working fine and then all of a sudden stopped. I've done a lot of checks on the server to figure out what has happened but have got nowhere.

If I run my .bat on any desktop, nothing happens, and no output.txt file is created

If I run my .bat on the actual SERVER2 it works fine, so the issue must be firewall/access related but i'm getting nowhere

Can anyone suggest;

1. how i can produce some sort of error files to give me a better idea of what the problem is?
2. what changes to check for in relation to access

Thanks in advance

EDIT if I just enter "sqlcmd -S SERVER2\MSSQL2012" on a command prompt window I get an error that sqlcmd is not a recognised command, do I need to have some SQL program installed? it worked fire before so I think not?

Comment: Give a try with SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows authentication in sqlcmd.

Comment: That doesn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: Anyone go any further suggestions on this one?